# How to shorthen a condition using a loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I've got six component array and I want to make sure that if a user is initializing values of components he/she won't give 2 or more the same numbers.

```
while (tab[i] == tab[i - 1] || tab[i] == tab[i - 2] || tab[i] == tab[i - 3] || tab[i] == tab[i - 4] || tab[i] == tab[i - 5])
    {
        cout << "Liczby nie moga sie powtarzac! Sproboj jeszcze raz: ";
        cin >> tab[i];
    }
```

I tried to do sth like:

```
while (for (int m = 1; m < 6; ++m)
   {  
     tab[i] == tab[i - m];
   }
```

but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Please provide further detail for your problem given: 1. It's not clear if you want to check the vector only after it is completely filled against a new item, as your check (eg: tab[i] == tab[i-5]) will point out of the array boundaries for all the first 5 items (for values of i from 0 to 4), 2. The "something" like code example is not correct from the C syntax point of view, 3. Please add comments in english, not in Polish, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but are you maybe looking for [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) or [std::any_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `std::find`:

```
while (std::find(&tab[i - 5], &tab[i], tab[i]) != &tab[i])
{

}
```

but, like your code, that only works for the sixth number.

To read six numbers without duplicates, you could do something like this:

```
int tab[6] = {0};
int i = 0;
while (i < 6) {
    do {
        cin >> tab[i];
    } while (std::find(tab, tab + i, tab[i]) != tab + i);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rather start with tab[0]: `std::find(tab, tab + i, tab[i])`?

Comment: @Aconcagua Good point. I tried to keep it close to the original.

Comment: I think he wants to initialize the entire array - and with his original code, he would produce UB as accessing the array out of its bounds...

Comment: A set, however, does not guarantee to retain the order in which the elements are fetched from the user - so this solution is only suitable if the order is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda:

```
auto const checkPrevDups = [&] {
    for (int m = 1; m < 6; ++m)
        if(tab[i] == tab[i - m])
            return true;
    return false;
};

while (checkPrevDups()) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also embed the lambda directly into the condition, but that'd probably look a bit bloated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that [std::any_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) is what you are looking for (assuming C++11):

```
#include <algorithm>

auto check = [&](int el){
    return tab[i] == el;
};
while( std::any_of(&tab[i-5], &tab[i], check) )
{
    cout << "Liczby nie moga sie powtarzac! Sproboj jeszcze raz: ";
    cin >> tab[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the checking loop into a function - better yet, use an already existing function (e.g. std::count):

```
while (std::count(tab+i-5,tab+i,tab[i]) != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Liczby nie moga sie powtarzac! Sproboj jeszcze raz: ";
    std::cin >> tab[i];
}
```

The more generic version that also works if `tab` is a `std::vector` or even a `std::deque` would be this:

```
while (std::count(std::begin(tab)+i-5,std::begin(tab)+i,tab[i]) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a nested for-loop to iterate through the array.

Look at this code to better understand what I mean:

```
    int array[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){ // set our element to check against all other elements
        for(int o = i+1; o < SIZE; o++) // iterate and check new element with our initial element
            if(array[i] == array[o]) // collision
                cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
                // put code here to make user re-input value
            else
                cout<<("ok")<<endl;
    }
```

The code above would not print "ERROR"

However, if you replaced the last index in array with a "1":

```
int array[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,1};
```

You will see this algorithm detects it and would print "ERROR"

Answer (score 0):

Staying in the while loop until all values scanned:

```cpp
int i = 0;
while(i < 6)
{
    std::cin >> tab[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        if(tab[i] == tab[j])
            goto DUPLICATE; // exit double loop
    }
    ++i; // no duplicates found, next input
    continue;
    DUPLICATE:
    std::cout << "Liczby nie moga sie powtarzac! Sproboj jeszcze raz: ";
}
```

*Edit:* It is always better to use code already existing - stealing `std::find` from molbdnilo:

```cpp
int i = 0;
while(i < 6)
{
    std::cin >> tab[i];
    if(std::find(tab, tab + i, tab[i]) == tab + i)
        std::cout << "Liczby nie moga sie powtarzac! Sproboj jeszcze raz: ";
    else
        ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [unordered set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/)

```
#include <unordered_set>

int main(){
    std::unordered_set<int> set;

    int input = 5;
    auto got = set.find(input);
    if(got == set.end()){
        //input is not found
        //add to set
        set.insert(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That very likely won't, however, retain the order in which the numbers where fetched from the user. *If* that is relevant, the answer is not suitable.

Comment: If he wants the order it is probably not suitable.
He might use 2 containers but that's only if the situation requires find to be so fast.